# 'Error' while starting react-native server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b86Il.png)

Anyone can help? i'm new in react native and getting that error while starting server

Comment: Try running it in a terminal outside of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It's 10months old post xD